# Remove infront of word with if

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm working on a script. I'm trying to print out a path that look somewhat like this: `/example/example/file`. If what I'm checking starts with  `/`  i do not print out the path I have in a variable that looks somewhat like this `path=/example/example`. But if it does not start with a  `/`  I add the path. What I want to to is that I want to remove the path in-front of the file.

```
If it starts like this:

/example/example/file.example

I want it to look like this

file.example
```

How can I do this in a if statement?

Comment: I'm maybe missing something in your question, but this seems an ideal use of `basename`: `fname=$(basename "/example/example/file.example")`

Comment: You're missing an example. "_If it starts with `/`_" seems reasonably clear. However, in your alternative scenario where it doesn't start with `/` you want to add the path ... but to what? So `/example/file.example` goes to `file.example` but what should happen to either `example/file.example` or plain `file.example`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ path=/example/example/file.example
$ echo ${path##*/}
file.example

$ path=example/example/file.example
$ echo ${path##*/}
file.example
```